# Ruby: Abusing mixin

Tags: refactoring, ruby, ruby-on-rails, code-organization, mixins

I'm currently working with some code that IMO has abused ruby's mixin features. Given that I'm new to ruby, I wonder if MO in IMO is correct or not.

My primary question is what makes more sense (and if there are any major technical differences between them):

E.g.

## 1

to create Helper singleton classes (or Modules with class methods) to keep all my "helper" functions.

```
module Helper
  def foo(); p 'foo'; end  # instance method
end

class User
  include Helper     # foo() is now a method of User

  def initialize()
    foo()            # included, invoked on User class object
  end

end
```

------- **OR** -------

## 2

create mixin modules that contain these functions and `include` them everywhere I need them.

```
module Helper
  def self.foo(); p 'foo'; end  # class method
end

class User
  
  def initialize()
    Helper.foo()            # Invoked on Helper module object
  end

end
```

---

An example of the way it's abused in my case:

```
module ComplexMathPerformer
  def perform_complex_math(); p 'perform_complex_math()'; end
end

module Renderer
  def render_3d_object()
    perform_complex_math() # from ComplexMathPerformer, which is NOT included here.
  end
end

module Game
  include ComplexMathPerformer
  include Renderer

  def play()
    render_3d_object()
  end

end
```

This code works because `Game` includes both `Renderer` and `ComplexMathPerformer`. But is a nightmare for someone who's looking at `ComplexMathPerformer` and trying to figure out where the hell is is `foo()` defined and how is it accessible in `ComplexMathPerformer`.

Logically it makes more sense to `include ComplexMathPerformer` but that's skipped because `Game` already includes `ComplexMathPerformer` (for it's own purposes). Making it a mess.

Comment: In the example you provide in #2, the dependency between Helper1 and Helper2 exists because you are declaring foo() inside Helper1. But you also allow that foo() is defined in the class itself.

Comment: @pietromenna I suppose you meant "But you ***CAN*** also allow that foo() is..." - In theory yes, but the in practice `Helper1 & 2` both have 7-10 related methods each (addressing different responsibilities) with a total of 150-200 LOC so it makes sense to keep them apart.

Comment: You got me right! I have one additional question: You separated Helper1 and Helper2 because who should use the methods of each one is different, right? For example, you have class A which only needs to implement `Helper1` methods, but class B does not need those, but only the ones from `Helper2`. The problem I see in the example is **coupling** between `Helper1` and `Helper2` modules, but not an abuse of mixin (which would be an abuse on abstractions)

Comment: @pietromenna It's more a dependency between `Helpers`, I updated the example to make a bit more clear.

Comment: Yeah, the class method approach is more immediately comprehensible but including a module is a fundamental thing that is frequently done, so its hard to say its abuse per se.

Answer (score 2):

By checking the examples, IMHO, there is no abuse of the mixin feature of Ruby, but [**coupling**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupling_(computer_programming)) between the modules `ComplexMathPerformer` and `Renderer`.

Mixin abuse is generally felt by developers when too much abstraction exists. Mixins should be used when you need to share behavior between a couple of classes.

Modules are usually used when you need to create functions more as **functions** (methods without state).

Maybe `ComplexMathPerformer` logic should be inside the game, or in another class which the Game consumes and not as a Module in your case.